# Cannot connect to MySQLi in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

-- fixed --

I fixed the issue that I was having. I'm not 100% sure how it was fixed, but I think it was because I changed the connection port to 3306 then connected using localhost rather than my ip. Thank you for everyone that took their time to help, you all were very helpful.

I'm having a **really** frustrating issue that I've been trying to fix for (literally) the past 4 hours. I cannot connect to MySQLi through my php code. I checked and the username, password, database, and host are correct. Here's my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("104.236.***.57", "Josh", "********", "******");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

All this does is echo Connected. The query doesn't return anything (it's like an empty string). When I try to echo $connection, it does the same. I think it's an issue with the connection because it was empty but you guys know best (I'm new to MySQL). I've researched and tried stuff for 4+ hours and nothing has worked.

Thank you so much,

Josh

edit: I've updated the code. Now it returns the error: Connection refused (mysql error).

I think I have fixed the connection issue, but I've ran into a new issue which I think may be related to the other issue. I have this code here:

```
$servername = "104.***.***.57";
$username = "Josh";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "*****";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

And it seems to work, except for that it prints '0 results' when there is 1.

Comment: `$query` is a result object (or probably, check for errors on the execution as well), you need to fetch.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? @chris85

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Specifically on the latter `Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.` so you either have `false`, `true`, or a `result object`.

Comment: @chris85 When I used `connect_errno`, I got an error when connecting. The error was: Connection refused.

Comment: I thought you said you got the `connected` message? `All this does is echo Connected`

Comment: @chris85 I did, but I was using `$connection->error` which seemed to not work. When I used `connect_errno`, it printed Connect failed: Connection refused.

Comment: It is strange that `connect_errno` is giving you an error message and not the error number. You should update the question with the code and your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php   
$servername = "localhost";  //replace your servername
$username = "root";   //replace your username
$password = "";        //replace your password
$dbname = "test";    //replace your database name

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    echo ' not connected';
}
else
    echo 'connected';
?>
```

execute this and tell me the output.

Comment: `Connection failed: Connection refused`

Comment: that means error in your connection string. do you working on local server or what ?

Comment: My server is on DigitalOcean

Comment: before it was working or you are trying for the first time ?

Comment: It was working on my previous host, but I got a new one with a new ip and now it's not (it's been a relatively long time since I tried it on my last host)

Comment: so  i think everything is correct in your side and the problem is with  the new host. check everything once more. everything is correct ?tell  me  which operating system are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 @Jok3r

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

Comment: That's what I was doing but I read some things and it said that the port was the issue. When I remove the other argument it does connection refused again.

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database); when you tired this what error came ?port error ?

Comment: Oh, that had the same outcome as when I put the IP in.

Comment: so your connection is ok now ?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, so yeah I think so. Now the query is having issues. @Jok3r

Comment: $result = $conn->query($conn,$sql); try now

Comment: <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                   echo "id: " . $row["id"];
                }
               
                ?>                                                                                             
                    try this instead of your code

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether Mysql is running or not. It usually happens when your droplet runs out of memory. In that case you can add a swap file to your droplet.

Comment: How do I check if MySQL is running @Sam

Comment: you can execute the following command.. # mysqladmin -u root -p status

Answer (score -1):

For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli::query (or mysqli_query()) will return a mysqli_result object (see this article [mysqli.query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)).
So in your case you can't just echo this, you can see rows data like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("104.236.***.57", "Josh", "********", "******");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* If we have to retrieve large amount of data we use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    /* prints number of result rows */
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
    /* Cycle through results */
    echo "Table data:\n";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        var_dump($row);
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Also, check your database server (104.236.***.57) made available for remote access. Check with your hosting company if you can access the database server from outside.

Comment: I've discovered that it's not the query that's giving me the issue, but it's the connection. I'll update the post.

Comment: Check your database server (104.236.***.57) made available for remote access. Check with your hosting company if you can access the database server from outside.

Comment: I found the error, but I don't know how to fix it. The error is: Connection refused (2002)

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "id: " . $row["id"];
}
```

Try this instead of your code.

Answer (score -2):

**//just fill your own settings...**

```
$server = "localhost"; 
$user   = "root"; 
$password = "*****"; 
$database = "uyelik";
$db= mysqli_connect($server ,$user, $password);
if(!$db) { echo 'Mysqli conn. error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno(); exit;}
mysqli_select_db($db,$database);
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM lists") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: `Mysqli conn. error: 2002` (sorry for the kinda late reply)